Bayesian inference in high-dimension for a non-linear multimodal model
Consider the following model: I am sampling a Bernoulli variable with a probability $p$ given by
\begin{equation}
p(\omega_i, \tau) := \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 n} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos (\omega_i \tau) \right] \; .
\end{equation}
The goal is to find the posterior distribution of $\omega_i$ by observing many samples of the Bernoulli variable. For large $n$, this becomes a high-dimensional, non-linear problem. Furthermore, the posterior distribution is expected to be multimodal due to the permutation symmetry of the $\omega_i$. To break the degeneracy in $\omega_i$, measurements must be performed with different values of $\tau$. As stated, my goal is to compute the posterior distribution of $\omega_i$ given a series of observed samples. I have attempted particle filtering (i.e., sequential Monte Carlo), but for $n=10$, the problem becomes intractable, and the posterior distribution fails to converge to the true values. I have access to a good GPU and would like to implement a fast Bayesian inference technique that can provide a rough estimate of the posterior when needed, but also allows for more time-intensive computations to converge to the true posterior.
What would be a good approach to this problem when MCMC is too slow? Variational Bayesian inference with normalizing flows seems like a potential solution, but it requires a good ansatz for the posterior, which is challenging to obtain due to the multimodality.

What prior on $\omega$ do you use?

Let us say that $\omega_i$ is uniform in $[0, 1]$.

Assuming some adequate prior $p(\omega)$ the posterior distribution after observing a dataset $\mathcal{D}$ of $M$ samples $\mathcal{D} = \{(b_m, \tau_m)\}_{m=1}^M$ is
$$
p(\omega|\mathcal{D}) \propto \prod_{n=1}^N p(\omega_n) \prod_{m=1}^M \left[ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos (\omega_i \tau_m) \right]^{b_m} \left[ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2 n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos (\omega_i \tau_m) \right]^{1-b_m}
$$
The posterior log-density can be easily computed and evaluated up to a constant (log-normalizing constant):
$$
\begin{align*}
\log p(\omega_{1:n}|\mathcal{D}) = &\sum_{n=1}^N \log p(\omega_n) \\ +& \sum_{m=1}^M b_m \log \left[ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos (\omega_i \tau_m) \right] \\+& \sum_{m=1}^M (1-b_m) \log \left[ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2 n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos (\omega_i \tau_m) \right] + \text{const}
\end{align*}
$$
Provided $\tau$ are not that large in absolute value, we can expect cosines to behave nicely (i.e. not vary too quickly) and the whole problem to be amendable to the modern approximate bayesian inference methods.
Black-box Variational Inference
In BBVI we pose the problem of finding the approximate posterior as an optimization problem, but unlike the classical Variational Inference we do not rely on finding a good class of approximate distributions, instead we can leverage the expressiveness of Neural Networks to give us a rich class of approximate distributions.
For example, using the normalizing flows you've mentions boils down to minimizing the following loss:
$$
D_\text{KL}(q_\theta(\omega_{1:n})\mid\mid p(\omega_{1:n}\mid\mathcal{D})) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{q_\theta(\omega_{1:n})} \left[ \log q_\theta(\omega_{1:n}) - \log p(\omega_{1:n}\mid\mathcal{D}) \right] \to \min_\theta
$$
Where $q_\theta(\omega_{1:n})$ is a normalizing flow, i.e. a series of bijections with easy to compute (log-determinants of jacobians) applied on top of a simple base distribution, say, a multivariate standard Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0, I)$. The beauty of it is that if you construct these bijections appropriately they will keep the bijectivity and efficiently of log-density evaluation, while being amendable to gradient-based parameter tuning. Then, by stacking many such transformations one would build a distribution with possibly thousands of parameters that can assume almost any shape you'd like (and hopefully something resembling the true posterior $p(\omega_{1:n}\mid\mathcal{D})$ as well).
Drawbacks of normalizing flows are:

All intermediate distributions need to operate in the space of the same dimension as the output, that is, the same dimension as $p(\omega_{1:n} \mid \mathcal{D})$, that is, $n$. While maybe not an issue in this case where $n$ is perhaps below hundreds, there are other methods that sidestep this requirement at a price of more approximations.
Normalized Flows layers are quite restricted in their design, as required by bijectivity and efficient log-det calculation. This might require more layers (=more computation) for the same level of expressiveness as with other models. However, this is only my intuition and I have no papers to back it up.

What architecture of a normalizing flow to use? Look into these:

RealNVP (and maybe it's successors Glow or Flow++)
Autoregressive Flow / Inverse Autoregressive Flow
Neural Spline Flows

Gradient MCMC
Another option is to use gradient-informed MCMC methods. While $\log p(\omega_{1:n}\mid\mathcal{D})$ is only known up to an additive normalizing constant, it's gradients w.r.t. $\omega$ are known precisely because they are not affected by such a constant. These gradients are naturally very helpful in high-dimensional problems as they can guide the sampling process towards high-probability areas. I won't delve into the details of such approaches, but some methods to look into are

No U Turn Sampler
Langevin MCMC

Software Implementation
Implementing these methods from scratch can be very tedious. In practice you'd like some software package to take care of as much as possible. Some options are:

TensorFlow Probability. Ships with a lot of Bijectors that you can use to make and train a normalized flow. Also comes with gradient MCMC.
Pyro. A pytorch analogue of TF Probability. Also has all the methods you'd want. Has a numpy-friendly version as well.
Stan a mastodon in the world of statistical inference, perhaps the best library for all kinds of MCMC.

